# Better approach for triggering directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, triggers, controller

I have a directive which needs to do some DOM manipulation based on the result of a service call in the controller. Following is the approach I am currently following:

1) Create a trigger object in each controller scope corresponding to each directive in view - to do dom manipulation when needed

2) Create the directive and do the dom manipulation based on the value set from controller;

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('myDirective', function (value) {
                if (value === "true") {
                    $(element).text("Scrolled to####" + $(element).data("scroll"));
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

3)From the respective controller method set the value to `true` to trigger directive functionality

```
app.controller("controller1", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.trigger1 = false;

    $scope.triggerDirective1 = function () {

        $scope.trigger1 = true;
    };
    $scope.trigger2 = false;

    $scope.triggerDirective2 = function () {

        $scope.trigger2 = true;
    };
}]);

<div id="c1" ng-controller="controller1">Controller 1
    <br>List 1
    <div my-directive="{{trigger1}}" data-scroll="20"></div>List 2
    <div my-directive="{{trigger2}}" data-scroll="30"></div>
    <button ng-click="triggerDirective1()">Trigger Directive 1</button>
    <button ng-click="triggerDirective2()">Trigger Directive 2</button>
</div>
```

Complete code is here -  http://jsfiddle.net/qec35dq4/

I find this approach not so good because of the following reason:

1) There will be multiple elements in view with the directive attached

2) Each Directive trigger is independent.At any single time only one directive would be in action.Depending on the number of directives in view, I have to keep track of all the trigger in the respective controller.

Is there a better way to solve this problem, so that the dependency of keeping track of this trigger scope object in controller can be avoided?.I thought of using `$broadcast/$emit,$on`. But don't think that will be a good solution either .Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:

New fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/86pk8LtL/

Changed the example a bit to reflect more on what I am trying to achieve - There will be multiple lists on page to which this directive will be applied.Based on the some logic from back-end some items need to be selected in the list. Once items are selected, the list should be scrolled so that the first selected item is in view(In the example,i am hardcoding the scrollposition using data attributes.But in reality directive would do the calculation).The purpose of this directive is just to handle the "scroll to view" part which is why I am somewhat sceptical in keeping a scope property for it. Please note that the current approach is working fine. Just want to see if there is any better approach to this.

Comment: I see that you're updating some `result` element with the text passed in `msg` along with the directive. Is that text static for that trigger  ?

Comment: Please ignore the logic inside the directive. That is just to indicate that the directive would be doing some DOM manipulation when triggered

Comment: As there's only one trigger active at any given time, is it correct to assume that other divs with different triggers will not be shown ?

Comment: Your sample is bit awkward,  would be easier to assist you if you had presented a more realistic code sample.

Comment: Updated the sample..also all the divs with triggers would be shown always..

Comment: Why does the directive need to do all the calculation?

Comment: Calculation means scrolling to the first selected item.Since this is related to DOM manipulation, I am doing it in the directive

Comment: _"But don't think that [$broadcast] will be a good solution either"_ - Why's that? You would achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: There can be multiple directives in page which would be receiving the broadcast and only one needs to be activated..In order to target the directive to be activated,i would need to pass some element information too with broadcast.That means controller should be aware of the DOM element in view, which is not a good practice in my opinion

Comment: In this example I would obviously move directive to button and then I don't need anything in controller. So you probably should describe real case.

Comment: `ng-click="trigger2=true"` seemed to work; i'm not sure what its doing, but the result looks the same as the others that call the trigger manually...

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is not really about using DOM querying like event driven libraries do.
I would suggest using controller fetching. 
Since Angular supports OOP standards try nesting your controllers, the scope of the child controllers is inherited from the parent controllers, that means you could observe the state of the which element is triggered. Take a look at this basic example http://jsfiddle.net/qec35dq4/3/
Also , I would suggest instead of observing attributes to pass a model into the directive's scope. That will help you to avoid observing for attribute changing.

Least but not last, you don't really need to watch for element's attribute change. It is available through the `attrs` of your directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('myDirective', function (value) {
                if (value === "true") {
                    $("#result").text(attrs.msg);
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT**
Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86pk8LtL/1/) based on your latest JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this last week. Cross element directive dom manipulation can be tricky assuming you don't want to write more than one directive, but when I did it I looked up elements I wanted by ID. This will save you from having to define methods on the scope.

```
<div id="trigger1"></div>List 2
<div id="trigger2"></div>
<button my-directive="trigger1" data-scroll="20">Trigger Directive 1</button>
<button my-directive="trigger2"  data-scroll="30">Trigger Directive 2</button>
```

And the directive.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var idElem = document.getElementById(attrs.myDirective);
                var elementToChange = angular.element(idElem);
                element.on("click", function(){
                    elementToChange.text("Scrolled to####" + attrs.dataScroll);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this directive: https://github.com/iameugenejo/ngScrollTo
It seems a very neat way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention two things

1. AngularJs is not about DOM Manipulation.
2. working concept of directive ,it must be purely independent from the controller and all, must be working in all place.

In my view the directive triggering must be on the basis of data.

So there won't be a problem in using multiple directive in a single view if they are triggered according to data